# Function inside a class does not work when calling it from vector<class> that contain all class objects

Tags: c++, oop

I have created a class named `institution` with a function inside of it called `add_student()` that takes a `string` and adds it to a `vector<string> accepted_students` within the class.

When I call the function directly through an `institution` object, it works.
But, when I create a vector that contains multiple `institution` objects and then call the function from a `for` loop by index, the function does not work.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class institution
{
public:
    string name;
    vector<string> accepted_students;

    institution(string NAME)
    {
        name = NAME;
    }

    void add_student(string student_name)
    {
        accepted_students.push_back(student_name);
    }
};

vector<institution> all_institutions;

int main()
{
    institution school("school_name");
    all_institutions.push_back(school);

    // The following line does not add somebody_name to school.accepted_students!
    all_institutions[0].add_student("somebody_name");

    school.add_student("my_name");
    
    //The following write "my_name" only. "somebody_name" was not added to the accepted_students vector.
    for (int i = 0; i < school.accepted_students.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << school.accepted_students[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am new to C++. I have created a similar code in Python, which works. But, it was slow.

Comment: `all_institutions.push_back(school)` pushes back a _copy_ of `school`. It's its own object.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `vector::push_back()` pushes a *copy* of `school` into the `vector`.  Thus, `school` and `all_institutions[0]` are separate `institution` objects in memory, each with their own `vector`.  So any changes made to `school` are not reflected in `all_institutions[0]`, and vice versa.

To make `school` and `all_institutions[0]` refer to the same object in memory, make `school` be a reference/pointer to `all_institutions[0]`.

Prior to C++11, you can use this:

```cpp
all_institutions.push_back(institution("school_name"));
institution &school = all_institutions.back();
//institution *school = &all_institutions.back();
```

In C++11 and later, you can use `emplace_back()` instead to construct a new `institution` object directly in the `vector` without having to push a copy:

```cpp
all_institutions.emplace_back("school_name");
institution &school = all_institutions.back();
//institution *school = &all_institutions.back();
```

In C++17 and later, `emplace_back()` returns a reference to the new object:

```cpp
institution &school = all_institutions.emplace_back("school_name");
//institution *school = &all_institutions.emplace_back("school_name");
```